# How can we use Oracle temp space effectively?

Tags: oracle

We are facing some issue with Oracle temp space. While inserting the data into table, it's quickly filling up and failing with unable to extend temp segment error.

Is there any way to overcome this scenario without adding extra temp file?

[image]

Comment: How many rows you insert at a time? `insert as select`?  How many insexes on the table? `select name , value from v$parameter
where name like '%area%' `

Comment: what is version RDBMS Oracle?

Comment: i want to insert 3.5 million records and Oracle version is "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production".

Comment: table contains 30 columns in that 7 columns are clobs.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query you are using.  [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

To get the total allocated space, used space, and available free space in your tablespaces you can use the following query:

```
-- Available space, by tablespace

SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT tablespace_name FROM dba_tablespaces)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes) AS total_bytes
     FROM dba_data_files
     GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, sum(bytes) AS used_bytes
     from dba_segments
     GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes) AS free_bytes
     FROM dba_free_space
     GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name);
```

There really isn't a way to "control" your use of temp space. The database will do what it needs to do. But inserting 3.5 million rows at one go is a lot of data. I suggest you restructure your population procedure to commit intermittently.

Best of luck.

Comment: 3.5 million rows is **not** "a lot of data" nowadays. Any decently sized production server should easily be able to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution for ORA-1652: unable to extend temp segment when doing insert clob](https://magnusjohanssontuning.wordpress.com/2015/09/25/ora-1652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-when-doing-insert/)